# NextJs <Link> doesn't rerun scripts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-link

When I use the `<Link>` tag in NextJs to navigate between pages it doesn't rerun my scripts after changing pages. It only runs the scripts after the first page load or when I press reload. When using plain `<a>` tags instead, it works fine because the page reloads after each navigation. As far as I can tell this happens because the `<Link>` tag makes it a Single-Page Application and doesn't refresh the page when navigating between pages.

I would greatly appreciate anyway to have it rerun the scripts when navigating between pages or to have it refresh the page without using just plain `<a>` tags and losing the Single-Page Application functionality.

This code doesn't refresh the page

```
 <Link href="/page1">
   <a>Page 1</a>
 </Link>
 <Link href="/page2">
   <a>Page 2 </a>
 </Link>
```

This code does refresh the page

```
 <a href="/page1">Page 1</a>
 <a href="/page2">Page 2 </a>
```

I load in all my scripts using a scripts component

```
export default const MyScripts = () => {
    
    return (
        <Script
            strategy="afterInteractive"
            type="module"
            src="/scripts/myScript.js"
            onReady={() => {
                console.log("Ready")
            }}
        /> 
    )
}
```

One thing I've noticed is that the above `onReady` function fires each time I change pages. Maybe someone knows how to run the `myScript.js` from the `onReady`.

Comment: Where do you use `MyScripts` component?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I use it on the index.tsx file of each page. As you would any other component.

Comment: Added a possible way of fixing it that I can't figure out how to implement (last two sentences).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Caution:** The hack of using `history.pushState` will not work reliably, especially when DOM elements need to be fetched using `document.querySelector*`. *Anyway, it's also better to avoid hacks if you can.*

The recommended way for Next.js is to use the [`Script` component](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/script) with the inline script.

Simply move the Javascript code from your `script` tag into a `Script` component. Remove the HTML `script` tag and any script file as you no longer need them.

```
import Script from 'next/script';

// Inside your exported component:
<Script id="myScript">
  // Paste the contents of /scripts/myScript.js here (and remove that file)
</Script>
```

Another clean way to do this is to use the `useEffect` React hook. In class-based components, you can use `componentDidMount`.

This idea was proposed here: [samplep182's comment in: Normal scripts "" not working after page navigation · Issue #4477 · vercel/next.js](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/4477#issuecomment-1016141210)

Simply move the Javascript code from your `script` tag into a `useEffect` block. Remove the `script` tag and any script file as you no longer need them.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

// Inside your exported component:
useEffect(() => {
  // Paste the contents of /scripts/myScript.js here (and remove that file)
}, []);
```

**Notes:**

1. It's recommended to have an empty array `[]` as the dependency list, to execute this on page load only.
2. For external scripts, please use the [`Script` component](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/script) with the `src` attribute.

Comment: thanks for this answer. I solved this while still learning react and didn't know about `useEffect`.

Comment: You're welcome, and thank you for accepting. (May I also ask for an upvote? :P) To me it seems that running the script on component mounting seems to be more correct than trying to piggyback on browser history movements. React can efficiently handle the hook at the appropriate time.

Comment: ill upvote once i get enough points. i need 15.

Comment: You have 23 now. LOL 

Comment: How to get content of external script?

Comment: @MegaProger Please do `import Script from 'next/script'` and use the [`Script` component](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/components/script) for external scripts. (To answer your question though, you can simply put the URL of an external script in your browser to grab the content. But this is NOT recommended for production use.)

Answer (score 1):

I used to [this](https://itsopensource.com/how-to-call-a-function-on-URL-change-in-javascript/) to solve it. It rerun what you want to be rerun each time the URL changes.

```
function name(history){
    var pushState = history.pushState;
    history.pushState = function(state) {
       // YOUR CUSTOM HOOK / FUNCTION
       console.log('I am called from pushStateHook');
       return pushState.apply(history, arguments);
    };
})
name(history)
```

My implementation in myScript.js

```
function myFunctions(){
    //my code
}

function urlChange(history){
    let pushState = history.pushState;
    history.pushState = function(state) {
        myFunctions();//I insert my code here
        return pushState.apply(history, arguments);
    };
}
urlChange(history);
```

Also I'm pretty sure `history.pushState = function(state){}` is what runs each time the url changes not the `urlChange()` function.

Comment: @juliomalves nope this still uses the Nextjs router. I just put it inside the external script and put all the functions I needed to run on each page reload into the "// YOUR CUSTOM HOOK / FUNCTION" portion. I just updated the answer to show exactly how I implemented it.

Comment: Right, I think I see what you mean. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @DanP nice hack. What's the `urlChange(history);` _(last line)_ for though? It looks like it will give an error since `history` is not defined.

Comment: @ADTC nope that line is required. `history` is an predefined object under the window object [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/javascript-history-object)

Comment: I think the mistake is you're declaring the function but also trying to call it on `window.history`. That doesn't look valid, and it doesn't do anything. You don't need that part `(window.history);` after the function declaration.

Comment: @ADTC yep your right. You don't need the `(window.history)` and `urlChange(history)`. I changed it to be just `(history)`.

Comment: It's still wrong. You cannot declare a named function and call it for execution in the same statement. [(See here.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtZfo.png) It has to be separate. [(See here for the correct code.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TcWiy.png)

Comment: @ADTC My bad, I didn't notice that. Should be good now.

Answer (score 0):

Could try to use the `router` object from the `useRouter` hook. Here's how you'd do that:

```
export const YourComponent = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  ...
  return (<>
    <button onClick={() => router.push({ pathname: '/page1' })}/>...</button>
    // Or you can also use a div if you don't want it behaving like a button
    <div onClick={() => router.push({ pathname: '/page1' })}/>...
  ...
```

If this doesn't work, then I'd check for what the code for the `Scripts` component is doing and how it's reacting to state.

Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's not explicitly mentioned in the next/script docs, the scripts added via the `<Script>` component stay mounted on navigation. This is THE optimization that the component is supposed to do:

- you don't define scripts in `<head>`, so the initial app load is faster
- you postpone script loading to the time when you visit the page where the script is needed (potentially pre-loading it with the whole page when using `<Link >`). `<script>` is added to the `body`. The script is often third-party code adding properties to `window`.
- when you navigate away, the script stays mounted in the `body` and `window` properties stay present
- later when you come back to the page you can make use of the previously loaded/mounted script

When you need to run imperative code each time the page is visited/mounted, I'd go for `useEffect`. If you need to re-run some script as a whole on mount (not just re-use some of the work already done by it), you can:

- access the script element and run the script again (from brief search, adding some URL param to `script.src` should work (`script.src += '?x=x'`))
- not use next/script at all and try to go with classic `<script>` tag - it should get mounted/unmounted just like other elements